# Bot Number guessing game with Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm doing some practice writing discord bots and I'm struggling with this game. The game is one where the user picks a number between 1-20 and the bot tries to guess it. I wrote it just fine outside of discord but trying to make this a discord bot is posing problems. The bot doesn't respond to my feedback and breaks with an error message. I'm pretty new to coding so this might be an easy fix that I'm not seeing.

The error I'm getting:

> is <message id=915045067356528681 channel= type=<messagetype.default: 0> author=<member id=870151920692625498 name='deftly test bot' discriminator='1827' bot=true nick=none guild=> flags=> too high (h), too low (l), or correct (c)?

```
import random
import discord
from discord import channel
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext.commands.core import check

client: Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
@client.command(aliases=['botguess'])
async def botg(ctx):
    low = 1
    high = 20
    feedback = ''
    await ctx.send('The computer will attempt to guess your number between 1-20.')
    def check (message): # check for author and message
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel
    while feedback != 'c':
        if low != high:
            guess = await ctx.send(random.randint(low, high))
        else: 
            guess = low
        guess = await ctx.send(random.randint(low, high))
        await ctx.send((f'Is {guess} too high (H), too low (L), or correct (C)?').lower())
        if feedback == 'h':
            high = guess - 1
        elif feedback == 'l':
            low = guess + 1
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'The computer guessed your number, {guess}, correctly!')
```

Comment: That's not an error.  It's printing exactly what you told it to.  What do you think `ctx.send` returns?  It's certainly not an integer.  It's not even a string.

Comment: @TimRoberts, Well if it's not a string or integer, what went wrong? I was able to use ```ctx.send``` before when I write the game the other way around. I'm not really understanding where I went wrong here. Sorry, but I'm genuinely not lost here.

Comment: You're getting a `message` object.  `ctx.send` sends a message, and returns a `message` object.  It does not read a response.  You need to use `bot.wait_for` to wait for a response.  It returns another object, and the `.content` method of that object has the string.